# Changing cells' color based on another cell value which is date

Tags: excel

How can I do this logical idea in excel:

Cell A contains date
Cell B has a value

If cell's A date is lesser than today and cell B is blank (does not have any value), then:
color cell B with red color.

I have the idea but I didn't know how to make it, neither from conditional formatting nor from excel formulas.

Does it need any VBA? or JS? because the file is on google sheets which does not support VBA as you know.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, do you use excel or google sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Select column A and define the conditionnal formatiing as follows

```
=and(B1="",A1<today(),A1<>"")
```